# Label is not updating as I am changing values

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I am writing a small program to manage store and price based on the item quantity. In the desire functionality I want the Grand Total of all items cost to be displayed in the label. This label updates as I change the values in qty text boxes.
So far I have done writing this code and it is working perfectly and even the values are exactly the same in variables as I want but the problem is label doesn't update even I have null values in the qty text boxes. It keep shows the previous total until I change the values, and it seems get stuck on the last updated total.

```
namespace wpfTest
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        List<int> myList = new List<int>();
        int val1, val2;
        int total;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            qtyTxt1.IsEnabled = false;
            priceTxt1.IsEnabled = false;

            qtyTxt2.IsEnabled = false;
            priceTxt2.IsEnabled = false;
        }

        private void chk1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (chk1.IsChecked == true)
            {
                qtyTxt1.IsEnabled = true;
                priceTxt1.IsEnabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                qtyTxt1.IsEnabled = false;
                priceTxt1.IsEnabled = false;

                qtyTxt1.Clear();
                priceTxt1.Text = "@50";
            }
        }

        private void chk2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (chk2.IsChecked == true)
            {
                qtyTxt2.IsEnabled = true;
                priceTxt2.IsEnabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                qtyTxt2.IsEnabled = false;
                priceTxt2.IsEnabled = false;

                qtyTxt2.Clear();
                priceTxt2.Text = "@100";
            }
        }

        private void qtyTxt1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (qtyTxt1.Text=="")
            {
                priceTxt1.Text = "@50";
                val1 = 0;
            }
            if (qtyTxt1.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                priceTxt1.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(qtyTxt1.Text) * 50).ToString();
                val1 = Convert.ToInt32(priceTxt1.Text);
                updateTotal();
            }
        }

        private void qtyTxt2_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (qtyTxt2.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                priceTxt2.Text = "@100";
                val2 = 0;
            }
            if (qtyTxt2.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                priceTxt2.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(qtyTxt2.Text) * 100).ToString();
                val2 = Convert.ToInt32(priceTxt2.Text);
                updateTotal();
            }
        }

        private void updateTotal()
        {

            lblTotal.Content = "";
            lblTotal.Content = (val1 + val2).ToString();

        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Total : " + total + "\n" + "Val1 : " + val1 + "\n" + "Val2 : " + val2);
        }

    }
}
```

I have also uploaded screen shot at my Microsoft OneDrive account because I have limitation here to upload photograph. :

http://1drv.ms/1lM0IdE

Comment: Which textbox shows Grand Total? Why is there "@"? Try to make your code simple and focus on your question. Besides, you may try ask in CSDN.

Comment: Sir, Grand Total is appearing on Label not on the TextBox. and @ stands for Price of time. @50 means Per 1 quantity the price is 50.

Answer (score 0):

Assign to Label Property Text

Try this

```
 lblTotal.Text = "";
 lblTotal.Text  = (val1 + val2).ToString();
```

Comment: Sir I am designing in WPF and here i do not get "Text" Property for label. As per your suggestion I also tried using another Textbox to display GrandTotal value (via Text Property) instead of label but it has the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

Well the first glaring problem is the fact that your trying to change the UILabel text through a "Content" property that doesn't exist unless you defined it yourself. You should be using the "text" property. Refer to the Apple documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html

Comment: Sir, I am designing program using WPF and here Label Class don't provide Text Property but here we have Content property for the same purpose. Secondly, as per your suggestion I also tried using another Textbox to display GrandTotal value instead of label but it has the same problem.